# Simulate HTML Hover with Touch on Multiple Divs

Tags: html, css, touch, jquery-isotope

I am trying to figure out how to simulate the hover/mouseenter functionality on iOS, with a touchmove event.

I would like to replicate the BigGraph hover effects on iOS. If you'r not familiar with it, link is below. Notice, when you hover over the squares they will expand, then collapse when the hover is removed.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/big-graph.html

In BigGraph, you'll notice the hover over behavior, I am trying to replicate that on a touch device. I am struggling to figure out a way to move your finger across the screen and make the boxes expand. Since hover is not supported, I was thinking touch move would be an option.

I have been able to expand the items with the touchstart and touchend events, but it appears that touchmove does not have a way to capture the DIV you are hovering over, and so I cannot capture the item to expand it.

Below is a simple snippet, any thoughts would be appreciated. 
thx

```
$(".item").bind("touchstart", function(e){
    log("touch start");
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.icon').css("background-color", "red");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".item").bind("touchend", function(e){
    log("touch end");
});

.big-graph .item:hover .icon {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
     -moz-transform: scale(3);
      -ms-transform: scale(3);
       -o-transform: scale(3);
          transform: scale(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to capture with touchmove. But to simulate hover of the boxes expanding and collapsing

```
$('.item').bind('touchstart', function() {
    // expand box
});

$('.item').bind('touchend', function() {
    // collapse
});
```

I don't think you need touchmove at all, unless I am missing something. Maybe there is a behavior that you wanted but not mentioned clearly?

Comment: In BigGraph, you'll notice the hover over behavior, I am trying to replicate that on a touch device. I am struggling to figure out a way to move your finger across the screen and make the boxes expand. Since hover is not supported, I was thinking touch move would be an option.

Comment: You are try touchmove and just return false, i am not sure what the effect of it would be but give it a try and see what happens. but usually people on touch device people woudld not drag their finger across like that unless they wanna swipe. so maybe you don't need to worry about that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iOS programmer but could you use multi-touch feature in some way? For example, 1-finger touch is a "click"; 2-finger touch is a "hover". Or a toggle button (click/hover).

Comment: This answer should be a comment.